# Apply 9patch and texture to button

Tags: android, xml, textures, nine-patch

I'm work on project where all buttons has paper-like background. Also buttons needs rounded corners and specific border. To make corners and borders I use nine patch. Here comes the problem! Using texture as background excludes nine patch btw nine patches can't stretch textures right way.

Is there any way to combine nine patch with texture? I tried to use `layer-list`and failed with it.

Update.
Here is my nine-patch (scaled)
[image]

And here is texture

[image]

Comment: show images of what you have tried and what you want to accomplish

Comment: I'd say **NO** (by definition of 9 patch), because the texture would become stretched as the 9 patch stretches. So even if you design your 9 patch with the texture finely applied, the result will reveal the stretching nature of the 9 patch. And, no, Android doesn't behave like a 3D program which paints the texture AFTER the object has been modified. You can try using libGdx or some other 3D engine.

Comment: @DerGolem maybe it's possible make custom view with such behavior?

Comment: Well, **YES**. It's an option to get what you want. So what you have to do is draw the stretched part first. Then make a black and white mask (since it's rounded). Prepare the tiled texture to fille the stretched image rectangle, with some alpha, let's say 50% (by guess). Now combine the two images using the mask to cut off the undesired square corners. It's quite a bit of a work, but it should go. At least, conceptually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I made custom class that extends `Button`. This class can apply texture to 9patch buttons accordingly mask.

```
public class TextureButton extends Button {

private final static String TAG = TextureButton.class.getSimpleName();
private BitmapDrawable texture;
private NinePatchDrawable ninePatchDrawable;
private Paint paint;


public TextureButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public TextureButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public TextureButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pattern300);
    texture = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    texture.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    Bitmap bitmapMask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_mask);
    ninePatchDrawable = new NinePatchDrawable(getResources(), bitmapMask, bitmapMask.getNinePatchChunk(), new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0), null);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
    texture.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    texture.setAlpha(255);
    texture.draw(canvas);
    ninePatchDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    ninePatchDrawable.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

}
```

As mask I use 9patch with white and transparent pixels.

Comment: I've been wanting to do something like this for a long time, knowing that a custom view was the answer. Will try it out!